# webpack - how to handle files from node_modules folders

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, node-modules

Sorry, I know this has been asked loads of times, but none of the answers appears to work in my case.

The scenario is that I'm writing an Outlook Add In (using the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial), it includes css files from node_modules and is run using npm start - clearly this works fine for development, but with an eye on production, I tried npm build and it works fine, apart from the fact it leaves all the references to node_modules/ intact, which needless to say, breaks the production files as the folder does not exist.

index.html (part, truncated irrelevant content)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Engage Demo</title>

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>

    <!-- LOCAL -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.components.css" />

    <!-- CDN -->
    <!-- For the Office UI Fabric, go to http://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more. -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/css/fabric.min.css" /> -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" /> -->

    <!-- Template styles -->
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

In an ideal world, I'd use a conditional compile statement which would swap the local links and replace them with the  CDN links in production build (but this approach appeared to be hugely convoluted)

So, removing the CDN links is fine, but how can I get webpack to move 'node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.min.css' to 'assets/css/fabric.min.css' ?

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfill: 'babel-polyfill',
        app: './src/index.js',
        'function-file': './function-file/function-file.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
             {
                 test: /\.css$/,
                 loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
             },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                // exclude: /assets/,
                use: [
                    {
                         loader : 'file-loader',
                        options :
                            {
                                name: "/assets/[name].[ext]"
                            }
                     }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfill', 'app']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './function-file/function-file.html',
            filename: 'function-file/function-file.html',
            chunks: ['function-file']
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            [{ from: './assets', to: './assets', toType : 'dir' }]
        ),
    ]
};
```

Any help would be gratefully received, I'm a PHP dev by trade and whilst I'm more than familiar with Javascript, the whole webpack and node thing is new to me and I'm finding the learning curve slightly steep!

TIA

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

With webpack, you have to have all your assets (any extension) included into your entrypoint (in your case, you can add to `src/index.js`). By doing that, webpack can understand all the dependencies that you are using and parse/compile/bundle them correctly and you don't run into these types of problems. You must not add links to your `index.html` manually, because by doing that webpack is not aware of what you are adding.

The correct approach, in your case is:

`index.js`:

```
import "office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.min.css"
import "office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.components.css"
...
```

These files are going to be in other chunks, which are going to be added by `Html Webpack plugin`.

Update:

To extract css from js files:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin/");


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfill: 'babel-polyfill',
        app: './src/index.js',
        'function-file': './function-file/function-file.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
             {
                 test: /\.css$/,
                 use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                 })
             },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                // exclude: /assets/,
                use: [
                    {
                         loader : 'file-loader',
                        options :
                            {
                                name: "/assets/[name].[ext]"
                            }
                     }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfill', 'app']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './function-file/function-file.html',
            filename: 'function-file/function-file.html',
            chunks: ['function-file']
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            [{ from: './assets', to: './assets', toType : 'dir' }]
        ),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that did initally simply baloon the size of the app.js file as it encoded the css into the JS file! I've changed that so it uses the file-loader and saves them into assets/css/ now - nearly done!

However, it doesn't update the index.html which is still pointing to node_modules/... can I get it to re-write the location the link tags point to, so it changes from node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.min.css to assets/css/fabric.min.css ?

I could simply change the hrefs, but then it would break it in dev mode..

Comment: Well, yeah it increases the size of app.js, but you should use MiniCssExtractPlugin (if webpack > 4) or ExtractTextPlugin (webpack < 3). This will remove the css from js and put them into separate css files. Html-text-plugin should update the hrefs using this. 

So i can update the answer, which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: according to npm, 4.6.0

Comment: @SteveChilds the version i posted is 4.x.x compatible, so go for it.